# How would I access the order in which I placed elements in a TreeMap in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

Let's say I put keys "a", "b", "c" into a `TreeMap`. How would I use "c" to determine that it was the third element in lexicographic order in the `TreeMap`?

What is the purpose of the NavigableSet obtained from a TreeMap?

Comment: A `TreeMap` orders it's entries by the natural order of the keys. If insertion order is important, you should use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it using a TreeMap?

Comment: No, because a `TreeMap` orders it's entries by the natural order of the keys and nothing else.

Comment: You seem to be going at your data structure selection backwards, picking the TreeMap class before deciding whether it meets your requirements. Normally, the first step is to decide what types of access are needed, and which are most performance critical. The second step is to look over the documentation for the various candidate Collection classes, if you are not already familiar with them, in the light of those requirements. Finally, pick the one that best fits the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you actually want to know is the index of the c key in the sorted set of keys contained in the map, you could simply use

```
int index = map.headMap("c").size();
```

Note that it doesn't have anything to do with insertion order, which a TreeMap doesn't maintain.

Comment: What order does a TreeMap maintain?

Comment: A TreeMap maintains its keys sorted, using their natural ordering, or using the ordering imposed by the comparator passed as argument of its constructor. So, if constructed without a comparator, "a" will be before "b", which will be before "c", whatever the order of insertion of these three keys. That's explained in the javadoc. Why don't you read it?

Comment: If created without a specified Comparator, a TreeMap is ordered by the natural order of the contents, which must be mutually Comparable. If it does have a Comparator, it orders its elements according to the Comparator.

Comment: I wasn't sure what's meant by natural ordering. If I have strings will it be in alphabetical order?

Comment: It will be by lexicographic order, to be precise.

Comment: How would I access a key's order in the TreeMap?

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me. What do you mean by "a TreeMap's order"?

Comment: My fault. The answer I was looking for was in your actual answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use LinkedHashMap if you want to retrieve the element in the order in which you insert.

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key
>   is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if
>   m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true
>   immediately prior to the invocation.)